# Generating random values without time.h

Tags: c, random, srand

I want to generate random numbers repeatedly without using the time.h library. I saw another post regarding use the

```
srand(getpid());
```

however that doesn't seem to work for me getpid hasn't been declared. Is this because I'm missing the library for it? If it is I need to work out how to randomly generate numbers without using any other libraries than the ones I currently have.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void) {
    int minute, hour, day, month, year;
    srand(getpid());
    minute = rand() % (59 + 1 - 0) + 0;
    hour = rand() % (23 + 1 - 0) + 0;
    day = rand() % (31 + 1 - 1) + 1;
    month = rand() % (12 + 1 - 1) + 1;
    year = 2018;

    printf("Transferred successfully at %02d:%02d on %02d/%02d/%d\n", hour, 
    minute, day, month, year);

    return 0;
}
```

[NB:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50285210/generating-random-values-without-time-h#comment87586416_50285273) *I can only use libraries `<stdio.h>` and `<stdlib.h>` and `<string.h>` — strict guidelines for an assignment.*

Comment: Note that both `time()` and `getpid()` are very (very, very) poor generators of random seeds.  Short of accessing a special device via standard I/O (note that `<stdio.h>` is a header, not a library), there aren't any good sources of randomness in the standard C functions from the headers listed.  Are you allowed to use POSIX functions from those headers, or are you restricted to standard C functions?  (Generating good random numbers is hard, and generating good random seeds is hard too.)

Comment: I do not know what a POSIX function is. It wasnt mentioned in the requirements so I assume so.

Comment: Put very crudely, POSIX is "the Unix interface" to the operating system.  You'd be able to find out far more than you ever wanted to know from the [POSIX 2017 standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm) — that's the 2017 update to POSIX 2008.  My guess is that if you've not been made aware of them, you're probably not expected to use them.  Is your platform Linux or another variant of Unix, or are you using Windows, or some other system?

Comment: I'm running the Ubuntu Bash subsystem on my Windows Laptop.

Comment: You can use anything for a random seed. No matter what seed you use, you will create a *semi-random* sequence (that is reproducible given the same seed). So for that matter, you are just as well off doing `srand (20180511);` as `srand (time (NULL));` with the benefit that you now know what the seed was and can reproduce the sequence if needed for debugging purposes. If you need random numbers for cryptographic purposes look at `getrandom` available since kernel 3.17 on Linux, or reading from `/dev/urandom`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> getpid hasn't been declared.

No, because you haven't included the `<unistd.h>` header where it is declared (and according to your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50285210/generating-random-values-without-time-h#comment87586416_50285273), you cannot use it, because you're restricted to using `<stdlib.h>`, `<string.h>`, and `<stdio.h>`).

In that case, I would use something like

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static int randomize_helper(FILE *in)
{
    unsigned int  seed;

    if (!in)
        return -1;

    if (fread(&seed, sizeof seed, 1, in) == 1) {
        fclose(in);
        srand(seed);
        return 0;
    }

    fclose(in);
    return -1;
}

static int randomize(void)
{
    if (!randomize_helper(fopen("/dev/urandom", "r")))
        return 0;
    if (!randomize_helper(fopen("/dev/arandom", "r")))
        return 0;
    if (!randomize_helper(fopen("/dev/random", "r")))
        return 0;

    /* Other randomness sources (binary format)? */

    /* No randomness sources found. */
    return -1;
}
```

and a simple `main()` to output some pseudorandom numbers:

```
int main(void)
{
    int i;

    if (randomize())
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning: Could not find any sources for randomness.\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%d\n", rand());

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The `/dev/urandom` and `/dev/random` character devices are available in Linux, FreeBSD, macOS, iOS, Solaris, NetBSD, Tru64 Unix 5.1B, AIX 5.2, HP-UX 11i v2, and `/dev/random` and `/dev/arandom` on OpenBSD 5.1 and later.

As usual, it looks like Windows does not provide any such randomness sources: Windows C programs must use proprietary Microsoft interfaces instead.

The `randomize_helper()` returns nonzero if the input stream is NULL, or if it cannot read an `unsigned int` from it. If it can read an unsigned int from it, it is used to seed the standard pseudorandom number generator you can access using `rand()` (which returns an `int` between 0 and `RAND_MAX`, inclusive). In all cases, `randomize_helper()` closes non-NULL streams.

You can add other binary randomness sources to `randomize()` trivially.

If `randomize()` returns 0, `rand()` should return pseudorandom numbers. Otherwise, `rand()` will return the same default sequence of pseudorandom numbers. (They will still be "random", but the same sequence will occur every time you run the program. If `randomize()` returns 0, the sequence will be different every time you run the program.)

---

Most standard C `rand()` implementations are linear congruental pseudorandom number generators, often with poor choices of parameters, and as a result, are slowish, and not very "random".

For non-cryptographic work, I like to implement one of the [Xorshift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift) family of functions, originally by George Marsaglia. They are very, very fast, and reasonably random; they pass most of the statistical randomness tests like the [diehard tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests).

In OP's case, the [xorwow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift#xorwow) generator could be used. According to current C standards, `unsigned int` is at least 32 bits, so we can use that as the generator type. Let's see what implementing one to replace the standard srand()/rand() would look like:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* The Xorwow PRNG state. This must not be initialized to all zeros. */
static unsigned int  prng_state[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

/* The Xorwow is a 32-bit linear-feedback shift generator. */
#define  PRNG_MAX  4294967295u

unsigned int  prng(void)
{
    unsigned int  s, t;

    t = prng_state[3] & PRNG_MAX;
    t ^= t >> 2;
    t ^= t << 1;
    prng_state[3] = prng_state[2];
    prng_state[2] = prng_state[1];
    prng_state[1] = prng_state[0];
    s = prng_state[0] & PRNG_MAX;
    t ^= s;
    t ^= (s << 4) & PRNG_MAX;
    prng_state[0] = t;
    prng_state[4] = (prng_state[4] + 362437) & PRNG_MAX;
    return (t + prng_state[4]) & PRNG_MAX;
}

static int prng_randomize_from(FILE *in)
{
    size_t        have = 0, n;
    unsigned int  seed[5] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    if (!in)
        return -1;

    while (have < 5) {
        n = fread(seed + have, sizeof seed[0], 5 - have, in);
        if (n > 0 && ((seed[0] | seed[1] | seed[2] | seed[3] | seed[4]) & PRNG_MAX) != 0) {
            have += n;
        } else {
            fclose(in);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    fclose(in);
    prng_seed[0] = seed[0] & PRNG_MAX;
    prng_seed[1] = seed[1] & PRNG_MAX;
    prng_seed[2] = seed[2] & PRNG_MAX;
    prng_seed[3] = seed[3] & PRNG_MAX;
    prng_seed[4] = seed[4] & PRNG_MAX;

    /* Note: We might wish to "churn" the pseudorandom
             number generator state, to call prng()
             a few hundred or thousand times. For example:
       for (n = 0; n < 1000; n++) prng();
             This way, even if the seed has clear structure,
             for example only some low bits set, we start
             with a PRNG state with set and clear bits well
             distributed.
    */

    return 0;
}

int prng_randomize(void)
{
    if (!prng_randomize_from(fopen("/dev/urandom", "r")))
        return 0;
    if (!prng_randomize_from(fopen("/dev/arandom", "r")))
        return 0;
    if (!prng_randomize_from(fopen("/dev/random", "r")))
        return 0;
    /* Other sources? */
    /* No randomness sources found. */
    return -1;
}
```

The corresponding `main()` to above would be

```
int main(void)
{
    int  i;

    if (prng_randomize())
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning: No randomness sources found!\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%u\n", prng());

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note that `PRNG_MAX` has a dual purpose. On one hand, it tells the maximum value `prng()` can return -- which is an *unsigned* int, not int like `rand()`. On the other hand, because it must be 2<sup>32</sup>-1 = 4294967295, we also use it to ensure the temporary results when generating the next pseudorandom number in the sequence remain 32-bit. If the `uint32_t` type, declared in `stdint.h` or `inttypes.h` were available, we could use that and drop the masks (`& PRNG_MAX`).

Note that the `prng_randomize_from()` function is written so that it still works, even if the randomness source cannot provide all requested bytes at once, and returns a *"short count"*. Whether this occurs in practice is up to debate, but I prefer to be certain. Also note that it does not accept the state if it is all zeros, as that is the one single prohibited initial seed state for the Xorwow PRNG.

You can obviously use both `srand()`/`rand()` and `prng()`/`prng_randomize()` in the same program. I wrote them so that the Xorwow generator functions all start with prng.

Usually, I do put the PRNG implementation into a header file, so that I can easily test it (to verify it works) by writing a tiny test program; but also so that I can switch the PRNG implementation simply by switching to another header file. (In some cases, I put the PRNG state into a structure, and have the caller provide a pointer to the state, so that any number of PRNGs can be used concurrently, independently of each other.)

Comment: I can only use libraries <stdio.h> and <stdlib.h> and <string.h> strict guidelines for an assignment.

Comment: @AngusRyan: Then you cannot use `getpid()`. Are you using Linux, perhaps? If so, you could seed the built-in PRNG from `/dev/urandom`. Do note it is very Linux-specific, though.

Comment: BSD (macOS and Mac OS X) have both `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom`, the latter documented as: _`/dev/urandom` is a compatibility nod to Linux. On Linux, `/dev/urandom` will produce lower quality output if the entropy pool drains, while `/dev/random` will prefer to block and wait for
     additional entropy to be collected.  With Yarrow, this choice and distinction is not necessary, and the two devices behave identically. You may use either._

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I did not know that (or have forgotten). Now I know; thanks!

Comment: Is there a way you could write an example that I could test. How do I implement /dev/urandom in the code above?

Comment: The original code (also mine) uses `open()`, `close()`, `read()` — translated to use standard I/O, it becomes: `static void random_seed_dev(const char *device, size_t size, void *data)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(device, "rb");
    if (fp == 0)
        err_syserr("failed to open %s for reading: ", device);
    size_t nread = fread(data, size, 1, fp);
    if (nread != 1)
        err_error("unexpected short read on %s: ", device);
    fclose(fp);
}` which can be called with the device name (`/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom`).  Functions `err_syserr()` and `err_error()` report errors and exit.

Comment: @AngusRyan: I've amended my answer, and also included Jonathan Leffler's note about device name availability.

Comment: Given that `srand()` wants an `unsigned` seed, you might use my function as: `unsigned seed; random_seed_dev("/dev/random", size(seed), &seed);`.  (I actually hide this behind an interface `void random_seed_bytes(size_t size, void *data);` — which I forgot while transcribing earlier.)

Answer (score 0):

> however that doesn't seem to work for me getpid hasn't been declared.

That's because you need to include the headers for `getpid()`:

```
   #include <sys/types.h>
   #include <unistd.h>
```

Another option is to use `time()` to seed (instead of `getpid()`):

```
   srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
```

Comment: that requires the time.h library which I am not allowed to use.

Comment: You need to seed it one way or other. You can *not* seed at all if you are happy that the same sequence of numbers are repeated each time your program is run. Other option is to pass your own seed as an argument and use it (i.e., pass that integer to `srand`). If you are on a POSIX system, you can use `lrand48`.

Comment: @AngusRyan They are header files, not libraries. I don't know why it's restricted that way for your assignment. You might consider `lrand48` as it's declared in `stdlib.h`.

Answer (score 0):

As other answer pointed, you need to include the `unistd.h` header. If you don't want to do that then put the declaration of `getpid()` above `main()`. Read the manual page of `getpid()` here http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html

One approach may be

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
pid_t getpid(void); /* put the declrataion of getpid(), if don't want to include the header */
int main(void) {

   /* .. some code .. */
   return 0;
}
```

Or you can use `time()` like

```
srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
```

Comment: cant use pid_t as its 'unknown name type'

Comment: your compiler will import `pid_t` implicitly while compiling, if not then open `vim /usr/include/unistd.h` & find the definition of `pid_t` and put into your code. I don't think your assignment make any meaning. Better see the source code for `srand()` implimentation