# Use rand() in C to get a different number every run without using time() or getpid()?

Tags: c, random

I am currently using the time() function inside srand() to generate a completely different and random number everytime the program is run.

```
srand(time(NULL));// chooses random seed for a different rand() every run 
  int n = 1 + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (100 - 1 + 1) + 1); // only generates numbers between 1 and 100
  printf("n = %d",n);
  int a = rand();
  printf("\na = %d",a);
  int b = rand();
  printf("\nb = %d",b);
```

Unfortunately, I have learned that I am not allowed to use time() or getpid(). Is there a way, using ONLY <stdio.h>, <stdlib.h> <assert.h> to generate a different random number every time the program is run?

Comment: See [random(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/random.3.html) for ideas.  Why the limit to `<stdio.h>, <stdlib.h> <assert.h>`?

Comment: You could ask for user input and use the `clock()` change between a real user's input to get a few bits.  Once you get enough bits, seed some [PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator)

Comment: Agreeing with @chux-ReinstateMonica above, it is generally considered a very bad idea to generate pseudo-random numbers with something as predictable as time as a factor. BTW, what are you using the generated random numbers for? Did you consider OS provided facilities for random numbers (e.g. `/dev/urandom` and/or `/dev/random`) ?

Comment: This is for a school project and we are restricted to those headers. It's okay to use pseudo-random numbers as this is just a project and not something that will actually be used. I haven't considered /dev/urandom as I don't know if we can use them.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica in the past I've seen Opera mini running on feature phones asking people to press the arrow keys several times to seed a random key

Comment: If I understand the requirements correctly, the following should work. Record in a file how many times the application has been invoked. Process this sequence number through a good mixing function (e.g. a reduced-round version of DES, or one of the hash functions by Bob Jenkins). Good avalanching behavior is essential (a change in any one input bit should on average change half the output bits). Feed the result into `srand()`.

Comment: @njuffa You don't need to "map" the sequence number to any other number. The sequence number can be used as a seed already. Especially on many Windows compilers, `rand()` is limited to [0..32767].

Comment: @thebusybee concerning seeding, it is not `RAND_MAX`  nor `rand()` that is important, but the bits used by `srand(unsigned)` - which is not limited by `RAND_MAX`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica In principle you are completely right. Experiences show that especially VisualC's `rand()` has a period of 32768, always in the same sequence. `srand()` just defines the first value. The same source compiled several years ago with a 4.x GCC did not repeat in a test of multiple weeks over billions of calls. -- Anyway, the OP "just" needs another sequence on each run, but there are no other requirements.

Comment: @thebusybee Agree  VisualC's `rand(), srand()` has historic weaknesses (e.g. short period) but its not the small `RAND_MAX`.  IMO, the implementation is hobbled in C to encourage other propriety langues.

Comment: @Immort8lSp8rt8n "to generate a different random number every time the program is run?" is the wrong goal.  A random number does not depend on prior runs.  Sometimes a repeated value is OK.

Comment: @thebusybee I suggested applying a mixer function before feeding the sequence number to `srand()` to avoid the following effect:`srand(1);rand();` returns 41; `srand(2);rand();` returns 45; `srand(3);rand();` returns 48;`srand(4);rand();` returns 51, etc.

Comment: Why do you think `rand()` does this? Does your library work like this? Mine gives quite different values. And as said, the requirement of the OP was just "different sequences", not a healthy distribution.

Comment: @thebusybee The example I gave was based on what `rand()` actually returns with my toolchain / system. Why does it do this? Presumably because is uses a PRNG of very poor quality. I agree that my *suggestion* exceeded the literal requirements as stated by OP, but in the direction of best practices, which I don't consider a bad thing.

Comment: So, you want to gather *entropy* from the user? Then use that *entropy* to seed C's library RNG? Ask the user to type a (large) bunch of characters, judiciously use a few of them to build your entropy (ignore repeats `aaaa...aaaaa`, finger switching `pqpqpq...pqpq`, ...).

Answer (score 1):

I think someone has answered your question here:
[Generating random values without time.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50285210/generating-random-values-without-time-h)

I think you can use a file with numbers and random your number from there, for example:

```
static int randomize_helper(FILE *in)
{
     unsigned int  seed;

    if (!in)
         return -1;

    if (fread(&seed, sizeof seed, 1, in) == 1) {
        fclose(in);
        srand(seed);
    return 0;
    }

    fclose(in);
    return -1;
}

static int randomize(void)
{
    if (!randomize_helper(fopen("/dev/urandom", "r")))
         return 0;
    if (!randomize_helper(fopen("/dev/arandom", "r")))
         return 0;
    if (!randomize_helper(fopen("/dev/random", "r")))
         return 0;

/* Other randomness sources (binary format)? */

/* No randomness sources found. */
    return -1;
}
```

and this is an example for main:

```
 int main(void)
 {
    int I;

    if (randomize())
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning: Could not find any sources for randomness.\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%d\n", rand());

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of impressed I haven't seen this method anywhere else, one day I was digging through some github repos, and I found a projet using a method to randomly seed srand() (I forgot which repo).

I find it very elegant, I don't know too much about how the computer decides where each function should be, but this seems to work very well, if anyone wants to correct/clarify, it would be great.

```
void seed(void)
{
    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    srand((unsigned long)&seed);
    return (0);
}
```

This was how I found it, but I've tried passing it the address of main instead of the address of seed and it seems to work too.

You don't really need a specific seed function, any function will do.

Now I'm pretty sure this is not a reliable method for pseudo-randomness but for small projects that needs just the simples implementation of something "random", without using time(), getpid() or a block of code, this will more than do.